# Read router log with snmp protocol

Tags: java, router, snmp

I am trying to solve the following problem for a client. My client has routes and switches. Some of the employees of the client can access those routers and perform commands on it. We have to find out which employee performed which command.

I heard that the routers and switches store those log information in them. Now all the routes and switches support snmp protocol. So, i want to send an snmp get request into the server and read those logs. But i could not find any way to do this with snmp protocol.

I have searched in the net but could not find anything to find out if router logs can be read with snmp. So , i am asking it here. How can i do it with snmp ?

I am using java in backend.

Regards,
Tanvir

Comment: You need to specify which routers / switches. Every vendor's MIB is different. For example for Cisco  https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11092696/snmp-trap-login-success-logtrap-not-working

Comment: You'll also need a MIB browser. When you can view the objects in the MIB browser, you can definitely make SNMP Get Requests using Java with SNMP4J or any other library.